# Looking to find out the name of a movie with tentacled monster on spaceships

Tags: story-identification

I saw this movie when I was a kid early 80's (the movie could've been much older as we barely had access to any TV shows where I grew up) and made me like sci-fi movies ever since. It takes place in space, a spaceships stops to investigate why a bunch of ships are clustered together in the middle of space. There was this tentacled monster with no face that travelled from one ship to another and killing the crew by grabbing them with the huge tentacles, putting them in its mouth and then spitting out an incinerated body. There was no escape as the monster seemed to move directly to the next ship.
I'm dying to see it again, gave me nightmares at that time but still a good fantasy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like the "[Dragon's Domain" episode](http://moonbase99.space1999.net/dragon.htm) of Space: 1999.

Pilot Tony Cellini on Moonbase Alpha, which is traveling the galaxy on Earth's wayward moon, is beset by memories of an earlier deep-space mission of which he was the only survivor. His vessel came upon a cluster of derelict alien spaceships and docked with one; while they're exploring it, a swirl of lights fills the main corridor and a one-eyed tentacle monster materializes. It grabs crewmembers and stuffs them into its maw, then spits out dessicated corpses. It uses some sort of mesmerizing ability to persuade its targets to give up resisting. Cellini escaped in the command section of his ship, but there was no evidence of the monster and he was accused of abandoning his crew. Cellini abruptly begins suffering nightmares and visions of the same swirling lights in Alpha...

Full script and related information at http://catacombs.space1999.net/main/tscript/z23dd.html

Comment: It is not "the same region of space", actually it's a very different region of space, *and yet* the ships' graveyard is there. Koenig and Bergman observe the uncanniness of it all, and if I remember correctly, Bergman says that the ships remind him of flies in a spider's web, and Koenig reminisces that it was strange, but Tony has never, in all his life, missed an appointment (this was in the Italian version, though).

Comment: Thank you jeffronicus and PMar, I just watched the clip on Youtube and that is the one I was looking for.

Comment: @LSerni Thank you for you the note; I've removed the reference to approaching the same region of space. Found the script at http://catacombs.space1999.net/main/tscript/z23dd.html There's even an argument between Commander Koenig and Victor Bergman. Bergman: "John, we're light years away from Ultra." Koenig: "Victor, the Moon has moved, so could they." Bergman: "But the coincidence."

Comment: @Diana , you can mark the answer as accepted then. Unfortunately I have already upvoted it, otherwise I'd upvote it again for the script link. (I see that the spiderweb reference is there; the one about missing appointment was probably a decoration by Italian translators. I *do* seem to remember much longer dialogues that are in the script...)